# Can someone solve this question: Show that $\ln(1+n)<n$ for all $n\ge1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I just started the option $1$ Calculus topic on Math HL, and I already have a problem I can't solve.

I think it uses mathematical induction, so I did the methods $n=1, n=k,$ and $n=k+1$. I am stuck after $\ln(2+k)>k+1$. I tried relating it with the $n=k $ part, but both show the same sign and it doesn't help me prove it. Can someone solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It is important that when you ask a question you show some of your own effort.  Otherwise it may attract downvotes and eventually be closed.

Comment: just try first few integers, and make a plot to see it. It will help you to get the idea

Comment: See [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619). You need to improve the question.  Kinda difficult to give a useful answer when you won't tell what tools you are familiar with. This is trivial with basic facts about derivatives in place. If you are still in the process of defining the natural logarithm, then you need a different approach.

Comment: FWIW: I rewarded the attempt to improve the question by retracting my vote to close for missing context. That reaction (=edit) was what I was looking for. Opinions may differ whether the question is now good enough. I refrain from further judgement, I can see the case either way.

Comment: You might want to consider de following when doing the inductive step:
$$
\ln(n+1+1) = \ln\left( (n+1)(1+\frac{1}{n+1}) \right) = \ln(n+1) + \ln(1+\frac{1}{n+1})
$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: For the induction step prove and/or combine the following

- $1+(n+1)<e(1+n)$,
- the natural logarithm is an increasing function,
- $\ln(ex)=1+\ln x $ for all $x$.

---

I assume that you haven't covered derivatives yet, and really need/want to do this by induction.

Comment: Think: To increase the right hand side of the inequality by one you simply need to add one to $n$. To increase the left hand side of the inequality by one you need to multiply whatever is inside the logarithm by $e$. Will these facts work for you when you try the induction step.

Comment: Oh, I see how it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Equivaently, show that $$1+n<e^n $$
for all $n\ge 1$. (Actually, this holds for all real $n\ne0$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Differerntiate both sides and conclude. Also note that $$\ln (1+x)\Big|_{x=1}<x\Big|_{x=1}$$**Comment**

This inequality is true for any $x\ge0$. The illustration below shows why:

[image]